# fixed button on the linearlayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

A have the button on the bottom of linear layout. The other content in this layout may change its height. Due to this the button moves up. How to make the button to be "fixed" on the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use RelativeLayout....
dynamic of your code

```
 RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rl.setLayoutParams(params);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Previous");
    LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    button.setLayoutParams(params1);
    rl.addView(button);
```